# How to grab JavaScript graph image from asp.net mvc/ C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a service which send an email on certain interval, the email is template based where I pass model to view and it return HTML String, it works fine. 
[Rendering-ASP.NET-MVC-Razor-Views-to-String](https://www.codemag.com/article/1312081/Rendering-ASP.NET-MVC-Razor-Views-to-String) for html and CSS.

[image]
Till now it is not automatic, where user click button and on that click event i am saving that graph first and then execute send email attaching those saved graph.

```
 function SaveAllImage() {
     bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to send fuel inventory email?<br/>", function (result) {
        if (result) {
            var fuelinventoryInputs = new Array();

            @foreach(var _tank in Tank) {
                <text>
                    var fuelInventoryInput = {};

                    fuelInventoryInput.TankId = @(_tank.Id);
                    fuelInventoryInput.Date = $("#txtEndDate").val();
                    var canvas = $("#DivTankLineGraph_@(_tank.Id) .canvasjs-chart-canvas").get(0);
                    if (canvas != undefined || canvas != null) {
                        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                        fuelInventoryInput.GraphImage = dataURL;
                        fuelinventoryInputs.push(fuelInventoryInput);
                    }            
                </text>
            }

            Ajax_CreateEdit_StateChange(1);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/FuelInventory/SaveAllImage",
                data: JSON.stringify(fuelinventoryInputs),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (r) {
                    //Ajax method to send email 
                    SendEmail();
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    Ajax_CreateEdit_StateChange(2);
                    bootbox.alert("Error while sending fuel inventory email.");
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Now my new requirement is to replace this manual process, but the problem is how to interpret that javascript to make graph and to get that graph to attach in the Emil.

```
var model = new Tuple<List<Tank>, Dictionary<int, object>>(Tank.ToList(), tankData);
var graph = ViewRenderer.RenderView("~/Views/FuelInventory/GraphForEmail.cshtml", model,null);
```

It uses ASP.NET MVC view engine render and gives me string, which string contains javascript as well, while rendering it can not interpret and execute JavaScript. [Out put of ViewRenderer.RenderView in application](https://github.com/bibashkafle/examples/blob/master/output.html)

Out put of same view on browser. 
[image]

Is there any way to achieve my requirement. I need to attach same graph in automatic email.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an embed webview. Generate the page -> load it into the webview -> store webview content as a picture after it was rendered. Something like this will do. https://cefsharp.github.io

On the other hand, do you *really* need to like use the js code to generate those graphs? There are LOTS of c# libraries that can make you any plot in no time! There are even nuget packages.

Comment: wouldn't that defeat the purpose of fetching the image via JS?